# create array from object values in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a similar function from [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#values) but the documentation says:

```
_.values({ 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 });
// → [1, 2, 3] (property order is not guaranteed across environments)
```

For my use, it is important that the order is preserved, my object will come from a result of mongoose.

I checked the source code:

```
function values(object) {
      var index = -1,
          props = keys(object),
          length = props.length,
          result = Array(length);

      while (++index < length) {
        result[index] = object[props[index]];
      }
      return result;
    }
```

It seems to me that it does keep the order, but why the warning on their documentation?

---

If objects don't have order then how would this work?

```
(function() { return _.toArray(arguments).slice(1); })(1, 2, 3, 4);
// → [2, 3, 4]
```

Isn't the order of the arguments important?

Comment: There is no order to preserve, objects don't have order.

Comment: @adeneo well, that makes sense... updated my question.

Comment: The warning means that, you may get different order in different JavaScript implementations.

Comment: @thefourtheye that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: **Arrays** have order because the ordering of the properties is intrinsically computable - it's just an increasing sequence of integers. You're free to impose any ordering you want, but the object itself won't do it. So you could get the object property names with `Object.keys()` and sort that array, for example.

Comment: `arguments` considered to be an "array-like" object. Which means it can  iterable via `for(var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++)` loop rather than `for(var name in obj)` loop.